# remove one seri from the legend chart in c#

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, charts

I used this code to display chart:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sql = "Select distinct(UserName),Sum(Value) from mytable       group by UserName";

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connectionString);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dt);
    chart1.DataBindTable(dt.DefaultView, "UserName");
}
```

It works and display my desired chart but in the legend shows two series. One with name of Series in blue color and the other is Columns with brown color. My chart columns are brown too. How can I remove blue series from the legend?

Comment: Try `chart1.Series.Clear();` at the beginning of your `Form_Load` method.

Comment: @jstreet Yesss. It works, Thankyou